# Running a build first in SCons

Tags: scons

I created a special builder in SCons for creating a virtualenv in Python from a requirements file. If given a flag `--virtualenv`, I would like to set an envrionment variable called `HOSTPYTHON` which changes the Python that scons use to build and test the rest of my code.

This means that I need the virtualenv builder to always run first and before all other builders. How can I do that?

Comment: Do you want to change the HOSTPYTHON flag only when --virtualenv is given on the command line, or should it also depend if the requirements file has changed?

Comment: Only if `--virtualenv` is given. But it's okay, I got this part, I just included here to clarify my intentions. The important piece is getting the build to run first.

Comment: The flag just states whether the rest of the builds use this environment, but it should be built if the requirements file changed regardless of this flag.

Comment: To clarify - this is a requirements.txt file in the format of `pip freeze`, which I then use to install packages in the virtualenv.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of defining the `virtualenv` as a builder, you could instead consider making it a simple Python function and run it using the SCons [Execute()](http://www.scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user/x3095.html) function. Execute will always be executed before any of the builders.

I dont know how to change the Python version being used by SCons in the middle of a build, so you may have to run SCons twice. The first time, check for the `--virtualenv` command line argument, call `Execute()` if present (or always call Execute() and check the cmd line internally), and then `Exit()`.

Comment: This will run the builder regardless of whether the requirements file changed, which will take up a lot of time.

Comment: It's obviously possible because you could manually take all the targets and make them depends on this build. The question is whether there's a convenient way to do so.

Comment: @AmirRachum, I didnt understand that it depended on the requirements file. If it does, then you're right. I asked the OP about that.